# Image Noise Detection in MATLAB

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am getting error while implementing a simple idea for noise detection in an image. Let  I  denote  noisy  image  and  for  each  pixel of  I  is represented by I(x,y). A Sliding window of size 3X3 centered at I(x, y) is defined. At first we estimate that the center pixel of window is noise or not. To differ the noise and signal, we calculate the mean (m) and standard deviation (s) of the window. If the pixel is between m-s and m+s then it is a signal otherwise noise and we will apply median Filter.

Algorithm:

```
1.  Read an Image I.
2.  Take a Sliding Window or Mask of size 3X3.
3.  Calculate the Mean (m) and Standard deviation (s) from the Mask.
4.  Calculate the threshold as follows 
         t1 = m-s and t2 = m+s

5.  IF     t1 <= I(x,y) and  I(x,y)  <= t2 THEN

           Result(x,y) = I(x,y)
    ELSE
        Result(x, y) = medfilt2(I(x,y)

6.  Repeat the step 3 , 4 and 5 on Entire Image.
7.  Display the Resultant Image.
```

I tried to implement this algorithm as follows

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

I=imread('lena.jpg');
I=rgb2gray(I);
J=imresize(I, [128 128]);
L = imnoise(J,'speckle',0.01);


[m,n]=size(L);
% RETAINING THE CORNER PIXELS/ we can do zero padding also, suggest me which one is good

for i= 1:m+4
    for j = 1:n+4
        L(:,1:2)=J(:,1:2);         % retain the first two columns
        L(:,(m-1):m)=J(:,(m-1):m); % retain the last two columns
        L(1:2,:)=J(1:2,:);         % retain the first two rows
        L((n-1):n,:)=J((n-1):n,:); % retain the last two rows
    end
end

for i=1:m-2 
    for j=1:n-2

      P=L(i:(i+2),j:(j+2));
      s=std2(P(:)); % Calculating Standard deviation
      m=mean2(P(:)); % Calulating Mean
      t1=m-s; % Threshold 1
      t2=m+s; % Threshold 2

      if (P(2,2)<=t1 && P(2,2)>=t2)
       iout(i,j)=medfilt2(P(:))
      else
       iout(i,j)=P(2,2)
      end


      end
end
L
iout
imshow(iout, []);
imshowpair(L,iout,'montage');
```

**It runs but there is no change between input and output images.. Image is not filtered.**
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This condition can never be satisfied: 
`if (P(2,2)<=t1 && P(2,2)>=t2)`.

It should be 
`if (P(2,2)>=t1 && P(2,2)<=t2)`

2) You haven't created iout. You should be creating it with: 
`iout=zeros(m,n)` at least before the beginning of second loop.

3) medfilt2 performs a median filtering. What you would like to write is `median(P(:))`.

4) This is not an error but for use with std2 and mean2 you can just use `std2(P)`, you don't need to `std2(P(:))`

Comment: I updated the code and got this error, Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in n1 (line 36)
       iout(x,y)=medfilt2(P(:))

Comment: I edited my answer. Read it again.

Comment: Ok..thank you.. i will try.. what to do if I want to apply different filter other than median by detecting noisy pixel this way

Comment: You can just use median and get the code working.

Comment: k.. It is running .. Taking too much time.. Can we implement this using blockproc ?

Comment: I am planning to use some other filter. To get code working, I tried with median, if it works, I thought that I could change medfilt2 to someother filter function(ex: anisodiff2) but you said that i should use median(P(:)).. That is why i asked you like that..

Comment: Still running.. Can you please implement the algorithm? I have been stuck with this for more than 2 day.. I have UG project review in a week.. It will be very much helpful, if you could implement this algorithm.

Comment: It is still running !

Comment: Yes in MATLAB you have neighborhood filtering:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html

Comment: Can you please implement the algorithm?

Comment: The algorithm is implemented. MATLAB is never designed for doing such things quickly. You might want to switch to C implementation if you need speed.
Well, I guess my help in getting your algorithm working is more than sufficient as an answer to this question since what you have asked was to correct the mistake in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do this faster, what you could try is the neighborhood operations. Take for example the sample code below:

`I = imread('tire.tif');
f = @(x) max(x(:));
I2 = nlfilter(I,[3 3],f);
imshow(I);
figure, imshow(I2);`

This applies a maximum filtering. You could consider changing your neighborhood function `f` to your custom algorithm (inside your loop) and this should give you a better speed.

Of course there are a lot of ways of getting speed. Use of integral images, moving averages and precomputations might save you from the burden of heavy block processing. But this would be way a lot to write in here. For more details check out these papers:

http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~shafait/papers/Shafait-efficient-binarization-SPIE08.pdf
http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1201/1201.5227.pdf

Cheers,

Comment: I did that.. but got error Check this one; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434482/error-image-noise-detection-in-matlab

Comment: So you cross-post now? 
I have answered it.